What's the best way to upload large files to S3 Buckets
I'm using Vue js to create chunks for Laravel 11 backend and from there these chunks should be transferred to AWS S3 Buckets.
I used an append for each new chunk, it was working but had plodding progress.
    // Upload a video to S3
    public function uploadVideo(Request $request)
    {
        // Upload chunks and if is_last is true, combine them
        $file = $request->file('chunk');
        $isLast = $request->input('is_last');

        $file = $request->file('chunk');
        Storage::disk('s3')->append('test/videos/rrr/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->get(), null);

        if ($isLast == "true") {
            // Change the privacy of the file
            $path = 'test/videos/rrr/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Chunk uploaded successfully',
        ]);
    }

I tried streaming and it seems that it's working to the end, but when I open the video file it shows a black screen.
    // Upload a video to S3
    public function uploadVideo(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('chunk');

        $stream = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r');
        
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('test/videos/streams/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $stream, 'public');

        fclose($stream);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Chunk uploaded successfully',
        ]);
    }

So what's the problem and the best way to fix it?
